# How can I control a HomeEasy Light Switch with a 433MHz Module(GPIO)?

Tags: remote, home-automation

I'm currently trying to connect my Pi to a wireless Lightswitch. The problem is though, that it does not work and I'm not quite sure why.

The Setup is as follows:

- Raspberry Pi 2
- 433MHz sender connected (5V, Ground, GPIO17)
- [Home Easy HE882](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B006HZJNLO/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [Home Easy HE842](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B006DCERZI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- wiringPi (just downloaded and built)

The switch (HE882) is correctly connected and works manually + the connection to the wireless one (HE842) works too, I can turn the light on and off with both of them.

I used the 433Utils to get the code from the HE842 (RPi_utils/RFSniffer), as I don't have any DIP on the switches.
The result here was "1066005" when I clicked on and "1066004" when I clicked off.

Next I tried to get the pi to send the code to the switch, so it turns the light on and off. Here I used "433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 1066005", the result though was just nothing.

I've also used rcswitch-pi for the send command, though I'm not sure I'm doing it right, as I'm actually not able to get any code for this send command...

Having the 433MHz Receiver still connected I could see the command being sent, though the light switch doesn't do anything.

I've also tried many implementations (domoticz, pilight, piHomeEasy), but there's always the same result.

Has anybody any experience with these witches? Am I doing something wrong or is there any possibility to debug something? Or are those switches just not fitting for the need (if so, any other suggestions?)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my experience those transmitters may not have much of a range especially at 5V.  Try it as close as you can get to the switch -- as in, not just in terms of feet but *inches*, hold it right up to the switch -- and do it in a loop with a one second delay for a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Try `codesend 1066005 0 207`. The `207` just indicates a slightly different pulse length.

This was needed for my Elekcity Wall sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I have example [433 sender/receiver code](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D).

It requires my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) daemon to be running.

If it doesn't work you could contrast what you are sending and receiving using my [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html).